# Button Get Shrink as I Press onClick Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, button

I am Working with the Buttons Which have a background that I have Created in Drawable `xml` File. The Buttons look Fine in Designing But on Runtime as I Press Click, its size get Shrink and When I Click on Other Button in Design the Previous button Size goes to initial Android...

here is My Button `Xml` File

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_facbookid"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_95sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners_main"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
    android:text="@string/url"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolorblack"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_facebook"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_facbookurl"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_facbookurl"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
    android:text="@string/facebookid"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_facebook"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_facbookid"   
    />
```

The selector drawable Layout layut i have Created for buttons is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#8420CA"
            android:endColor="#46CEFC"
            android:angle="45"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="4dp" />
        <!--corners allow us to make the rounded corners button-->
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_50sdp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The Scenario is as i Click on Button It Changes its color, It changes the color but Button get Shrinked

```
 btn_facbookurl.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        btn_facbookurl.background= 
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners)
        btn_facbookid.background= 
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners_main)
        btn_facbookurl.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.whitecolor))
        btn_facbookid.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.textcolorblack))
        url_facebookedit.setHint("Enter Facebook ID Here")
    })
    btn_facbookid.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        btn_facbookid.background= 
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners)
        btn_facbookurl.background= 
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners_main)
        btn_facbookid.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.whitecolor))
        btn_facbookurl.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.textcolorblack))
        url_facebookedit.setHint("Enter Facebook URL Here")
    })
```

here is the UI[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic 2]

As I click on Button Facebook it Shrink and Come to origional Size as I Click on URL and Vice Versa...

Comment: show image please

Comment: Just Adding the Image

Comment: Please share UI

Comment: I have Just Shared

Comment: `btn_facbookurl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);`

Comment: It will be better if you set height value `android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"`

Comment: The Buttons Size remains same as i Press a Button

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a transparent stroke around the button (which makes the filled area smaller)

```
<stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="4dp" />
```

I assume that file is `R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners`, and the stroke isn't there in `R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners_main`.

Also check your corner radius, I don't know what `sdp` is but if the radius doesn't match in both files, and one is slightly larger, it might affect the size since it's defining the entire shape and not just the corners. Maybe!

Answer (score 1):

For your Button ***Shrink*** case, You should add [**`android:layout_height`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_height) value.

> Specifies the basic height of the view. This is a required attribute
> for any view inside of a containing layout manager

**Don't**

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Try with

```
<Button
      android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
```

Comment: The Shrinking Issue on the Remain the Same after applying the height